# Problem with logits and labels size. Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to train top layer separate from base model. All is working with generating features with `model.predict_generator` like

```
bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
    train_generator, predict_size_train)
np.save(save_dir + 'bottleneck_features_train.npy', bottleneck_features_train)

train_data = np.load(mtx.save_dir + 'bottleneck_features_train.npy')

model.fit(train_data, ....
                    )
```

But now I got huge dataset and can't load all data in memory so I use generator `flow_from_directory`

```
def create_generator(root_path, batch_size):
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    root_path,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True)

return generator
train_generator = create_generator(mtx.train_data_dir, mtx.batch_size)
```

and than

```
model.fit(train_generator...
```

class_mode in `flow_from_directory` is "categorical" and loss function `too(categorical_crossentropy)`

layers is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(7, 7, 512)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))

model.add(Dropout(0.7))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

but when I run training I get

> logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[24,32] labels_size=[4,32]

As I understand it's something wrong with shapes in layers or how are features/labels encoded.

Update 1:

Also it's working when `batch_size` in `flow_from_directory` is set with 1. But accuracy is very low than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(224,224,3)))
```

Comment: Well. It worked, but gives very small prediction accuracy.
I figured out the problem.
So as it is transfer learning and we need to learn on predictions generated by pre-trained network we have to make input layer with (7,7,512) input_shape. Because features generated by vgg16 have that shape.

So as solution i made a custom generator for features. That resolves question with training on huge dataset(actually huge amount of features generated by pretrained model)